# Non-intruding cluster analyses of two separate group of samples

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm having some trouble with cluster analysis. The idea is that I want to cluster two different groups of samples separately, but I want to maintain a rule: a cluster within one group can't be intruded by any cluster of another group. This example will illustrate-

```
#Let's make type-1 group of samples
x1<-sample(seq(1,1.3,by=0.02))
y1<-sample(seq(3,3.3,by=0.02))
x2<-sample(seq(1.5,1.8,by=0.02))
y2<-sample(seq(3,3.3,by=0.02))
x3<-sample(seq(2.5,2.7,by=0.01))
y3<-sample(seq(4.5,4.7,by=0.01))
x4<-sample(seq(1.5,1.8,by=0.02))
y4<-sample(seq(2.4,2.7,by=0.02))
d1<-rbind(cbind(x1,y1),cbind(x2,y2),cbind(x3,y3),cbind(x4,y4))
d1<-data.frame(d1,type=rep(1,69))

#Let's make type-2 group of samples
x1<-sample(seq(1.3,1.5,by=0.01))
y1<-sample(seq(2.8,3.2,by=0.02))
x2<-sample(seq(2.3,2.4,by=0.005))
y2<-sample(seq(2,2.1,by=0.005))
x3<-sample(seq(2.7,3,by=0.02))
y3<-sample(seq(1.6,1.9,by=0.02))
d2<-rbind(cbind(x1,y1),cbind(x2,y2), cbind(x3,y3))
d2<-data.frame(d2,type=rep(2,58))

#plot them
plot(d1$x1, d1$y1, xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(1.5,5))
points(d2$x1, d2$y1, col='blue')
```

[image]

[The figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vX2JPWHhxRGhUWGc/edit?usp=sharing) clearly shows that one cluster of type-2 samples is inside 3 separate clusters of type-1 samples. However, one group of type-1 is clearly clustered further apart. If I want to make 3 clusters, the algorithm makes one cluster of the type-1 that are on the left and right of the central blue cluster, one of the bottom cluster, and one of the farthest cluster-

```
#taking only the coordinates for cluster analysis 
myd1<-d1[,1:2]
myd2<-d2[,1:2]

#clustering using stats package
(cl1 <- kmeans(myd1, 3))
(cl2 <- kmeans(myd2, 3))

plot(myd1, xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(1.5,5), col=cl1$cluster)
points(myd2, col=cl2$cluster)
```

But I want one cluster of type-1 to be the cluster on the left of the type-2 central cluster, one will be comprised of the top and bottom one, and the third one with the furthest points. In this way, the clusters of type-1 will never intrude the clusters of type-2. I produced this dummy data just to illustrate the idea. Making 4 clusters of type-1 will solve the problem, for sure, but that can't be applied to the real data which is very complex. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for http://crossvalidated.com but first, you should set a seed for reproducibility. How did you arrive at 3 clusters? Can you show us an elbow plot (wss by cluster)? K-means may not be appropriate for your data. See http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/bio2/lectures09/clustering.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The clusters definitely don't look like k-means-clusters to me.

Your problems sounds like **constraint clustering** to me. Your constraints are must-not-link constraints between members of different groups.

The most obvious solution to your requirement of "non intruding" is to **split your dataset**, and cluster each part separately. This sounds boring, but it **guarantees** exactly your requirement.

You may also want to look at Generalized DBSCAN. Neighbor predicates in GDBSCAN can be defined to take group membership into account. I.e. neighbors are only members of the same group. But again, that is probably equal to running DBSCAN on each partition, then joining the two noise <strike>clusters</strike> sets.